# React.js authentication

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-redux, jwt

I have a react and redux app where a user is logged out after a certain amount of time. I am storing a jwt token in local storage and removing it when it expires. In my app.js file I do the logic to check if its there and if its expired, but that code only runs when the app is refreshed, I am trying to find a way for it to constantly run the expiration logic or better yet run it everytime the current route changes, rather than on a refresh. Thanks in advance.

basic structure:

```
imports 

expiration logic 

class App extends component {
render() {
   return (
         ...
         )
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you set up your store at the app's entry point. At that point, when the store is in scope, I would add an event listener to the window to detect route changes (you could use a `setInterval()` too...), and then use the store's `getState()` and `dispatch()` methods directly.

```js
// entrypoint.js (pseudo-code)

// imports...
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';

import App from './components/App';

// create the store
const store = createStore(...)

// listen for route changes
window.addEventListener('popstate', () => {
  const token = store.getState().jwt;

  // handle the case where the token hasn't been set yet
  if (!token) return;

  // test to see if the token is expired and dispatch something if it has
  if (token.isExpired()) {
    store.dispatch({ type: 'TOKEN_EXPIRED' });
  }
});

render(
  <Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>,
  document.getElementById('<your-apps-attachment-point>'),
);
```